# Minicom: send string when newline is detected

Tags: usb, minicom, uart

I have 3 different USB-to-UART FTDI cables and use minicom to debug some device.
My problem is only one of these cables can buffer characters until I send a newline. Eg when I type the string "help", the device on the other side will not output the help string until I press Enter. The two other cables don't seem to wait for a newline when sending, typing the same string "help", I am seeing no output and newline will just add new lines to whatever I have typed.

I have enabled the following settings each time I start the minicom session:

- echo on
- linefeed on
- carriage return on

The cables I am using are:

- TTL-232R-3V3 (this one works)
- TTL-232R-3V3
- TTL-234X-3V3

Initially, I thought this was an issue with the cable but because another TTL-232R-3V3 has not worked, I think this may be a minicom configuration. But I can't find any configuration that would control this behaviour for my minicom session.

Comment: buffering characters until you send a newline sounds like a job for the software running on your PC, not for the relatively slim logic that you need to convert a USB RX buffer ring into a UART output. So I agree with the assessment that this might be minicom behaviour.

Comment: It might as well be an issue with your "some device". Connect two cables with a null-modem cable and test with two terminal programs. As an alternative to `minicom` you could also try `seyon`.